# How to sort a dictionary by value where the key is a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
 d = {('08', '10010'):6, ('23', '10017'):6,('06444', '10028'): 6,('21', '10027'): 6}
```

I want to sort it by the second value

If I have an item `(x,y):z`, I need it to be based on y

I did something like this but it doesn't work out

```
print sorted(d, key=lambda item:item[0][1])
```

any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean, "It doesn't work out"? What is the result you expect, and what is the result you get?

Comment: Use `itemegtter` `sorted(d,key=operator.itemgetter(1))` as per the dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems:

1- To sort by second value of key-tuple, you forgot the .items() invocation

```
>>> print sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item:item[0][1])
[(('08', '10010'), 6), (('23', '10017'), 6), (('21', '10027'), 6), (('06444', '10028'), 6)]
```

2- If you need a dict where keys are sorted by that criteria, you need an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) object, because in a default dict keys' order is not guaranteed

```
>>> print dict( sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item:item[0][1]))
{('23', '10017'): 6, ('21', '10027'): 6, ('08', '10010'): 6, ('06444', '10028'): 6}
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> print OrderedDict( sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item:item[0][1]))
OrderedDict([(('08', '10010'), 6), (('23', '10017'), 6), (('21', '10027'), 6), (('06444', '10028'), 6)])
```

Answer (score 1):

almost there...

```
sorted(d,key=lambda x: x[1])
[('08', '10010'), ('23', '10017'), ('21', '10027'), ('06444', '10028')]
```

note that this is the sorted list of the keys, not the dictionary. To get the full view of the dictionary (with values) change `d` to `d.items()`

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds. :)